# PHP string highlight from mySql proximity search

Tags: php, sql, string, highlight

I would like to highlight the part of text that this query found:

Exemple 1:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE columnA regexp 'work.{0,10}john.{0,10}smith'
```

Highlight: "I have been **working for John Joe Smith** for the last 5 years"

Exemple 2:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE columnA regexp 'jo.{0,10}ba.{0,10}tur'
```

Highlight: "I have been working for **Joseph Balsora Turgeon** for the last 5 years"

I need to find the start position for highlighting in the string, I can figure out the end no problem.

I don't have a clue even after some research.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your data, for example all rows in your data are similar to eache other? Sentence pattern is all same? like I have been working for <name surname> for <number> years

Comment: can you add more details your code? or your php code? and also what is identifier to be hightlighted like (My Hightlight)  with using bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the same regular expression in php. E.g.:

```
<?php 
  $str = "I have been working for John Joe Smith for the last 5 years";
  // Assuming you get the $str from the database

  $highlighted = preg_replace('/work.{0,10}john.{0,10}smith/iu', '<b>\0</b>', $str);

  print $highlighted;
  // I have been <b>working for John Joe Smith</b> for the last 5 years
```

Note, you need to enclose the regular expression in some pair of symbols (like `/`...`/` in the example above). In the end there are modifiers. `i` allows to perform case-insensitive match, `u` allows to work with Unicode strings/

**UPD**

also probably you can perform the same replacement directly in MySQL:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('I have been working for John Joe Smith for the last 5 years','work.{0,10}john.{0,10}smith','<b>\\0</b>') ...
```

Comment: what if surnames are different? I assumed "smith" word is dynamic

Comment: @AterLux Great stuff! Exactly what I was looking for. Yes, the string comes from a search result in a database as stated in the query above. The search words comes from $_POST["searchWords"] (I know about injections, I will get to it when everything works). The second recommendation seems to need the search result before doing the search? I will test in the full database, I'm worried that it could be really, I mean really slow! Thanks, you made my day... and more ;o)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will show bold on the HTML side so you do not have to run regexp on DB side, you can apply on PHP:

```
<?php
$string ="I have been working for John Joe Smith for the last <number> years";
$highlighted = preg_replace("/(working for .*)(for)/", '<b>\1</b> for', $string);

print $highlighted;
// I have been <b>working for John Joe Smith</b> for the last <number> years
?>
```

The idea is finding and grouping "working for * for" then put them into 2 groups as "working for *" and "for", then replacing just the first group.

Comment: @Ibrahin Doğan: The problem is that I don't know where is the position of «work.{0,10}john.{0,10}smith» when the query return the search result. In this case, I don't know that «working for» is before John.